# Convert From JArray List to JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

I have looked at other similar questions but cannot figure out the answer for my particular situation.

I am creating a json file that will be parsed by another program (not mine so can't rewrite). The end product needs to be an object, not an array. So far I have only been able to create a JArray with the data that needs to be included.

I created a model to list all the json properties. I created a list to call the model and assign values to each property.

How can I have an end json file that contains all the required information but not in an array format? Right now I keep receiving the error message: 
"object serialized to array jobject instance expected"

```
public class CreateSummaryModel
{
    public CreateSummaryModel(){
        CreateAddressModel = new CreateAddressModel();
        ProductName = new ProductName();
    }

    public CreateAddressModel CreateAddressModel { get; set; }
    public ProductName ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class CreateAddressModel
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class ProductName
{    
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

List<CreateSummaryModel> output = new List<CreateSummaryModel>();
    foreach (var product in order.product.name)                                
      output.Add(new CreateSummaryModel()

     { CreateAddressModel =
      { City = order.address.city },
       ProductName = 
       { ProductNames = order.product.name },                                    
       });

  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
  File.WriteAllText(fullPath, json.ToString());
```

I have tried:

```
JObject jobjectObject = new JObject();
jobjectObject = JObject.FromObject(output);

AND
JArray jobjectArray = new JArray();
jobjectObject = jobjectArray.ToObject<List<CreateSummaryModel>>();

AND
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobjectObject);
string jsonD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CreateSummaryModel>>(json);
```

The end product is required to be in this format:

```
  {    
    "address": {
      "city": "Rivendell"
    },
    "productName": [
      "productName": "Lembas Bread",
      "productName": "Mushrooms"
    ]    
  }
```

Comment: This other program that is reading your json file should have some kind of documentation saying what kind of object it expects, right? It can't read just _any_ kind of object, right? Mind sharing what this program is actually doing to the file?

Comment: I have not seen the code. I have been informed the information from my json file is read and parsed out. If my file info is encased in an array, then the information cannot be parsed. If the data is surrounded with { }, it is okay. If the data is surrounded with [ ], then the data is not read.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the format that is required.

Comment: The JSON you showed is not valid json. You can't have `:` in an array. If that's supposed to be a dictionary, the key `productName` is duplicated.

Comment: Each title is designated to be followed by a " : ". The end result should not be an array. I do not know why I am able to get " : " when I run the code but it does need to be there in the end. I use a list with my model but should I use dictionary instead? I can take out the extra productName.

Comment: The question is, can your "other program" read the file you generate if it hasn't got `:`? i.e. just a simple array: `"productName": ["Lembas Bread", "Mushrooms"]`.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood earlier. Yes, the program can read "productName": ["Lembas Bread", "Mushrooms"].

Comment: I edited my answer. Does it work now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model classes you created are structured quite differently from what the "other program" expects.

The sample JSON that you showed is not valid JSON. Assuming that you meant:

```
 {    
    "address": {
        "city": "Rivendell"
    },
    "productName": [
        "Lembas Bread",
        "Mushrooms"
    ]    
 }
```

The model classes for this would be:

```
public class CreateSummaryModel
{
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("productName")]
    public List<string> ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And you can populate your model like this:

```
var output = new CreateSummaryModel();
output.Address = new Address { City = order.address.city };
// I didn't quite understand what your "order" object contains.
// I assumed it has a bunch of products with names.
output.ProductName = order.products.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting visual studio to accept 'Select'. I am referencing system.linq.

Comment: What is the type of `order.product`? @MapinTX

Comment: A field from Product Order.product .  order.product.name is a string.

Comment: I have implemented your code and it works well except for the Select. I replaced that line with: foreach (Order Order in orderProperty.order.Values)
                            {
                                output.ProductName.Add(order.product.name); };      The foreach does loop through the different product names but now the problem is that a new file is written for each product name and overwrites the previous file with the previous product name. I am trying to get it to add all product name values to the same file.

Comment: The code is now working. It needed to check for the file and if the file existed, deserialize, run through logic, and re-serialize.